# Prevent from scientific notation numbers in Yii2 kartik export to excel cell format

Tags: excel, yii2, format, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I'm using `kartik export` widget for exporting my grid view in `excel`. I am able to export all the data but there is an issue, I have a column name `imsi` which is in text, but after exporting it this column is having all the same numbers i.e. all the IMSI numbers are same. See below

[image]

[image]

**Grid Columns**

```
 $gridColumns =[
                [
                    'class'=>'kartik\grid\SerialColumn',

                ],
                 'id',
                ['attribute'=>'imsi','format'=>'text'],
                'sim_number'
  ]
```

How can I set the correct format? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause your cell data (imsi) is number. excel or some other programs. when size of cell is fewer than lenght of number. they change number to Scientific number or some thing like this.

to prevent from doing this. you must increase width of cell.

```
$gridColumns =[
    ['class'=>'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'id',
    [
        'attribute'=>'imsi',
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'width'=>'200px',
        'format'=>'raw',// or text
        'value'=>function($model){
            return $model->imsi.' ';
        }
    ],
    'sim_number'
]
```

**update:** after discussion. we found when we add spaces to value it will be force to text.

`PS.` If you want to use this numbers from excel file. you must `trim` to remove spaces.

Comment: I have tried your solution but still the issue remains same

Comment: @Faisal mybe `200px` is not enough. did you increase it to bigger ?

Comment: yes I increased it to `2000px` but still same issue

Comment: If you didnt handle numbers after exporting. you can add some symbol in your column. see this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/452832/turn-off-scientific-notation-in-excel/1301584) unfortunately this is problem of excel viewer. it force your data to scientific notation

Comment: can we change the notation?

Comment: @Faisal 

Unfortunately excel does not allow you to turn this functionality off by default.

However if you select your data, right click, and click "Format cells..." and choose Number you can stop excel from changing your data to scientific notation.

Comment: Yes it can be done but the main problem is that the data is already changed before formating it

Comment: I have already attached a snapshot of this issue in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204770/discussion-between-ttrasn-and-faisal).

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$gridColumns =[
    ['class'=>'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'id',
    [
        'attribute'=>'imsi',
        'contentOptions' => ['cellFormat' => DataType::TYPE_STRING], 
    ],
    'sim_number'
]
```

remember to include

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  'attribute'=>'imsi',
  'value' => function ($model) {
    return ' '.$model->imsi;
  }
],
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @C.O. - this is not a link-only answer, in fact it does not contain any links,  - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29308122).

Comment: I was being an idiot, the review que had a link to the SO post on top and I mistook that as the "answer" in question, sorry.